# orphanRemoval=true bidirectional OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm a little confused with bidirectional OneToOne relationship, and removing of orphans. These are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    public Long _UID;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="city", orphanRemoval = true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Mayor mayor;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "mayor")
public class Mayor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    public Long _UID;

    @OneToOne(optional=false)
    public City city;
}
```

And if I try this transaction:

```
City c = em.find(City.class, (long) 1);
AssertNotNull(c.getMayor());//gives true
Mayor m = new Mayor("Ed", "Lee");
c.setMayor(m);
m.setCity(c);
em.flush(); //This creates new Mayor and adds it to City, but don't delete an old one.
```

If I set mayor to null and flush before set new one, it works:

```
City c = em.find(City.class, (long) 1);
AssertNotNull(c.setMayor());//gives true
c.setMayor(null);
em.flush();
Mayor m = new Mayor("Ed", "Lee");
c.setMayor(m);
m.setCity(c);
em.flush(); //This creates new Mayor and adds it to City, but don't deletes an old one.
```

I use Hibernate 4 as JPA2 implementation.

Comment: 1. can you try without `(optional=false)` ???... 2. you have to do `em.clear()` after `em.flush()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Hibernate (and actually in the JPA spec).

See [this bug report](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5559) for more on the problem's background, and on possible workarounds. There is [another ticket](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6484) on the same issue that you can vote for, as the former is already closed.

Answer (score 0):

1. please remove `(optional=false)`
2. you have to do `em.clear()` after `em.flush()`

Comment: Thanx, but with the same effort :(